# How to find dynamically defined method with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wanted to know how `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` method is defined.

So I've checked source code but I couldn't understand what is going on.

```
# Executes the SQL statement in the context of this connection.
def execute(sql, name = nil)
end
undef_method :execute
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c13284131511fb7871a85659dd0b5e821d9ad29b/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb#L55

Perhaps the method is defined another place dynamically.
How can I find place where the method is described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are defined in respective adapters.

The adapters are in the following directory names as *_adapter.rb:

```
activerecord-x.x.x/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/
```

You can see the the definition of the `execute` method inside those files. like: `mysql_adapter.rb, postgresql_adapter.rb etc.`

Comment: Thanks. Now I can find proper .rb file.

Answer (score 1):

The method you show is defined in the module `DatabaseStatements` which is `include`d into the class `AbstractAdapter` (connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb).

`AbstractAdapter` simply serves as a base class for the various specialised database adapters for the different database servers Rails interoperates with; it's not intended to be instantiated on its own. For instance, the definition of `execute` for PostgreSQL databases is in [postgresql/database_statements.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c13284131511fb7871a85659dd0b5e821d9ad29b/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb#L126), as part of `class PostgreSQLAdapter < AbstractAdapter`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't noticed this is a abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

To know how `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` method is defined you should look in the connection adapter class you're using.
For instance, in case you're using mysql db (via mysql2 gem) you'll find the `execute` method definition you're using here:
[`activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb#206`](http://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb#L206)